# C# async/await in backend service / webservice usefull?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

Is `async`/`await` useful in a backend / webservice scenario?

Given the case there is only one thread for all requests / work. If this thread awaits a task it is not blocked but it also has no other work to do so it just idles. (It can't accept another request because the current execution is waiting for the task to resolve).

Given the case there is one thread per request / "work item". The Thread still idles because the other request is handled by another thread.

The only case I can imagine is doing two `async` operations at a the same time is like reading a file and sending an http request. But this sounds like a rare case. Is should read the file first and then post the content and not post something I didn't even read.

Comment: Question sounds like your are dumping your mind map in textual format.

Comment: And it sounds like someone thinking that web services have only one request at a time to handle, which sounds awfully - no idea how one even gets the idea outside of very rare edge cases.

Comment: Thinking about async/await as a delegating work to another thread is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Given the case there is one thread per request / "work item". The Thread still idles because the other request is handled by another thread.

That's closer to reality but the server doesn't just keep adding threads ad infinitum - at some point it'll let requests queue if there's not a thread free to handle the request. And that's where freeing up a thread that's got no other work to usefully do at the moment starts winning.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to read your question without feeling that you misunderstand how webservers work and how `async/await` & threads work. To make it simple, just think of it like this: `async/await` is almost always good to use when you query an external resource (e.g. database, web service/API, system file, etc). If you follow this simple rule, you don't need to think too deeply about each situation.

However, when you read & learn more on these subjects and gain good experience, deep thinking becomes essential in each case because there are always exceptions to any rule, so there are scenarios where the overhead of using `async/await` & threads may transcends their benefits. For example, Microsoft decided not to use it for the logger in ASP.Net Core and there is even a comment about it in the source code.

In your case, the webserver uses much more threads that you seem to think and for much more reasons than you seem to think. Also when a thread is idling waiting for something, it cannot do anything else. What `async/await` do is that they untie the thread from the current awaited task so the thread can go back to the pool and do something else. When the awaited task is finished, a thread (can be a different thread) is pulled out of the pool to continue the job. You seem to understand this to some degree, but perhaps you just don't know what other things a thread in a webserver can do. Believe me, there is a lot to do.

Finally, remember that threads are generic workers, they can do anything. Webservers may have specialized threads for different tasks, but they fall into two or three categories. Threads can still do anything within their category. Webservers can even move threads to different categories when required. All of that is done for you so you don't need to think about it in most cases and you can just focus on freeing the threads so the webserver can do its job.

Answer (score 0):

> Given the case there is only one thread for all requests / work.

I challenge you to say that this is a very abstruse case. Even before multi core servers because standard, asp.net used 50+ threads per core.

> If this thread awaits a task it is not blocked but it also has no other work to do so it 
>   just idles.

No, it goes back into the pool handling other requests. MOST web services will love handling as many requests as possible with as few resources as possible. Servers only handling one client are a rare edge case. Extremely rare. Most web services will handle as many requests as the plenthora of clients throw at them.